# php query, final calendar result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, calendar

Hello to everyone out there,

I'm trying to establish a calendar system for a garage planner. Therefore I have been doing a videotutorial on YT.

I'm almost done and stuck at the final query which is supposted to spit out the "events" on specific day.

A almost fully working demo can be seen here [Calendar Demo](http://sandbox.reifengundlach.de/calendar/show_calendar.php)
Also, I provide all files as a download here [Calendar Tutorial SRC-Code DL](http://sandbox.reifengundlach.de/calendar/calendar.rar)

The problem is, that it doesn't excecute the final query - I don't know why.
It does connect to the database at this point, but the query doesn't even echo the "close" button of an event, giving me the notion, that the script doesn't proceed until that point.

Here is the query source of the file events.php

```
$deets = $_POST['deets'];
// $deets = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $deets);

include_once('inc/connect.inc.php');

$events = '';
$query = mysql_query('SELECT description FROM events WHERE evdate = "'.$deets.'"');
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($num_rows > 0){
    $events .= '<div id="eventControl"><button onMouseDown="javascript:overlay();">Close</button><br />';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $events .= '<div id="eventbody">'. $desc . '<br /><hr><br /></div>';
    }
}
echo $events;
```

If somebody could give me hint what makes the trigger fail, that would be great.

Thanks in advance for your ideas and help.

greetings

Toby

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: I'm aware of this fact, I tried to use the *i version of the querys, but this way it will fail right from the begin. The Tutorial is 1 year old, but it has some good logic to learn in it i think.. Wish I could do better, no question :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to work through your code and check everything is as you expect.

If I understand you correctly, this is returning false: `if($num_rows > 0){` In which case, before your query echo out `$deets` and make sure it's the value you expect so know that works in the query.

Also, try adding this:

```
if (!$query)
  {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  }
else
  {
    echo "Query ok";
  }
```

blank out from your `num_rows()` with `/* */` just while testing and try the above.
Also, is there anything useful in your PHP error log?

As pointed out, mysql_ is being depreciated and you should use prepared statements in PDO or mysqli. At least use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your var `$deets` before using it in your query...

Comment: Thank you for giving me a hint. I'll check it out and be right back.